# Finding a differential operator

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, operator-theory, partial-derivative

Is there a differential operator $\mathscr{O}_{x,y}$ such that

$$
\begin{align}
\mathscr{O}_{x,y}e^{x\rho+y/\rho}=\frac{1}{1+\rho^2}e^{x\rho+y/\rho},
\end{align}
$$

with $\rho$ some (real or complex) parameter ? How can I write an equation whose solution may give $\mathscr{O}_{x,y}$ (if it happens to exist) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there's no point in including mixed partials in $\mathscr{O}_{x,y}$, since $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y} e^{x\rho + y/\rho} = e^{x\rho + y/\rho}.$

So writing
$$\mathscr{O}_{x,y} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i(x,y) \frac{\partial^i}{\partial x^i} + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i(x,y) \frac{\partial^i}{\partial y^i}$$
and applying it to your function gives
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i(x,y) \rho^i + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i(x,y) \rho^{-i} = \frac{1}{1+\rho^2}$$
and you can turn this into a set of equations on $a,b$ by multiplying both sides by $1+\rho^2$ and looking at the power series term-by-term, e.g.

\begin{align*}
a_0 + b_2 &= 1\\
a_1 + b_1 &= 0\\
a_i + a_{i-2} &= 0,\ \forall i \geq 0\\
b_i + b_{i-2} &= 0,\ \forall i > 0.
\end{align*}

It's easy to see that no solution exists involving only finitely many terms. There are many (formal) solutions if you allow infinitely many terms, e.g.
$$\mathscr{O}_{x,y} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^i \frac{\partial^{2i}}{\partial x^{2i}}.$$

Comment: Simple, austere, elegant answer. La ringrazio.